# poisonous vs venomous

Tags: переклад, from-english

В англійській мові є два терміни poisonous і venomous, які чітко відрізняються. Перший про тварин, які отруюють, якщо їх з'їсти, другий про тварин, які самі можуть вжалити\вкусити отруйною речовиною.

Підкажіть будь ласка як правильно вони перекладаються українською?
Бо наразі я вживаю *"отруйний"* щодо обох випадків.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стаття [Інтерферентна паронімія: отруйна — отрутна](https://enigma.ua/articles/interferentna-paronimiya-otruyna-otrutna) ([архів](https://archive.is/bctUs)) повністю відповідає на це запитання:

**Отрýйний** (англ. *poisonous*) — a) що містить отруту; б) який викликає отруєння.

**Отрýтний** (англ. *venomous*) — а) що є отрутою; б) який виділяє отруту.

Знали цю різницю такі словники, як: Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов), Словник української мови 1927-1928рр. (Б. Грінченко, вид. 3-тє, за ред. С. Єфремова, А. Ніковського), Словарь російсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.), Українсько-англійський словник 1955 (К.Андрусишин, Я.Крет), — проте радянські словники «раптово» гублять її, цю сакральну різницю.

Із сучасних словників тільки Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р. (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш) та Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки) 2010 р. (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович) розрізняють «отрутний» і «отруйний».

Знали також цю різницю і багато українських клясиків:

> - Туман розносить важке **отрутнеє** дихання долини (Дн. Чайка)
> - Збирали вони і препарували риб, раків, змій і ящірок... навіть **отрутних** тарантулів (Зінаїда Тулуб)
> - Страх бере за розум і чесноту мого пана, коли такі тарантули **отрутні** домують вкупі з ним (Леся Українка)
> - Джмелі збірають той мед із де-яких **отрутних** квіток (О. Стороженко)
> - Дитина його загине, скоро тільки не покине він вогкого, **отрутного** для життя місця (С. Єфремов)

[image: Різниця між "отрутний" та "отруйний"]

Comment: @Sasha, ваше посилання не резолвиться, виправте будь ласка.

Comment: O_o. Моє посилання якраз у мене резолвиться, а оригінальне enigma.ua в Україні заблоковане (тому я й додав снапшот, щоб можна було хоч якось подивитися).

Comment: Я буду радий, якщо Ви зробите снапшот якимось іншим чином (щоб снапшот резолвився в нас обох). Але, по-моєму, це необов'язково (ті, хто в Україні, можуть відкрити archive.is, ті, хто за кордоном, можуть відкрити enigma.ua).

Comment: @bytebuster, дякую за таку грунтовну відповідь ! А мені он таке питання прийшло в голову: а чому ми кажемо на речовину від якої стає зле "отрута", а не "отруйна" ? Ми ж її пємо, за попередньою логікою правильніше було б щось типу "отруйна"

Comment: @bytebuster, о ми то колеги ! Привіт .Net програмісту з Івано-Франківська )